# Hierarchy vs separate Dimensions

Tags: data-modeling, dimensional-modeling

I understand that Kimball recommends to flatten out hierarchy in single table. Eg: Product->Product Sub Category->Product Category should be stored as follows:

```
Product desc - Product Sub Category - Product Category
Nike xyz - Sports shoes - Shoes and Apparels
Adidas abc - Walking shoes - Shoes and Apparels
Nike jeans - Jeans - Clothing
Levi Jeans - Jeans - Clothing
```

The above structure works fine for transaction facts that come at product level

But what if Summary Facts need to be built at parent level of hierarchy eg, separate summarized facts needs to be built at product sub category level and category level? (The BI tools didnt perform well, hence decision is to physicalize these summary tables)

Keeping the product dimension as-is, can we also create separate physical Dimensions each for Product Sub Category and Product Category? Or can we/should we create these separate Dimensions as Views using "select distinct ... from product dimension"?

Thanks
Sunny

Comment: You create “aggregate” dimensions at the same grain as your aggregated fact tables. So you might create a Dim for sub-cat + cat and a Dim just for cat

Comment: Thank you Nick. Does this aggregate Dimension have to be a View created using "select distinct product category from product dim"  or can it be physical tables?

Comment: I would always use tables and not views